# LUIS bot does not take in account singular / plural intent

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding, microsoft-skype-bot

We are creating a bot and using LUIS as an interface, which is a requirement. On LUIS we have implemented intents and utterances. We are facing a problem for achieving a scenario on usability. To be precise there are utterance created for each intents, and these utterances does not take in account singular / plural intent.

The below are the steps I followed,

1. I have created a intent "Report"
2. I inserted some utterance for the intent,the utterance as showed in screenshot
3. After train and test with the word "reports" and "generate reports",the result didn't return the 'report' as top intent Note : Don't configure the Plural('reports') of 'report' word as utterance

[image]

Please provide us any solution or alternatives to achieve this functionality.

Comment: How many utternaces do you have in each Intent? Are you positive you want any sentence containig "Report" or "Reports" to be detecte as "generate reports" Intent?